# pandas: generate scores based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
import random, string, time
import pandas as pd

random.seed(1)
toy_set = pd.DataFrame({'group': [str(i)+'_'+str(j) for i in range(40000) for j in range(25)],
                        'feature1': random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k = 1000000),
                        'feature2': random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k = 1000000),
                        'feature3': random.choices(range(10), k=1000000)
                        })

#create hypothetical scoring dict
eventScores = {}
for k in toy_set.groupby(['feature1', 'feature2','feature3']).groups.keys():
    if k[0] not in eventScores:
        eventScores[k[0]] = {}
    if k[1] not in eventScores[k[0]]:
        eventScores[k[0]][k[1]] = {}
    eventScores[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]] = random.randint(1,10)   

def calc_x(subset):
    return subset.apply(lambda x: eventScores[x['feature1']][x['feature2']][x['feature3']],
                            axis =1)

t = time.time()
toy_set['x'] = calc_x(toy_set) 
print(round(time.time() - t))
```

I have a `df` with 3 features based on which I am generating a score for each line (in this case the score for each case is randomly specified just for the purpose of the example).

Is there a faster way to generate `x` rather than doing the nested `dict` replacement?
(This set is currently taking me ~30 secs on my W10 I7 , while the actual one is x15 larger)

Comment: What score? do you want to generate a new column score, with random values?

Comment: no, I want to generate the `x` column in my `df` faster - question edited to make it clearer

Comment: but can you explain how you are using the 3 features to generate score?

Comment: I believe it is pretty obvious from the script: e.g. `if feature1 == x and feature2 == y and feature3 == z: score = predefined_value` ..and so on for each combination of the 3 features

Comment: Flatten your dictionary, and then `.map()` to it or store your scores in a different dataframe and merge with it. There's many options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `dict comprehension` to restructure `eventScores`, then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) against your concatenated features:

```
d_map = {f"{k1}_{k2}_{k3}":v3 for k1, v1 in eventScores.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items() for k3, v3 in v2.items()}

toy_set['x'] = (toy_set['feature1'].astype(str) + '_' + 
                toy_set['feature2'].astype(str) + '_' + 
                toy_set['feature3'].astype(str)).map(d_map)
```

#### Timings

```
# This method
898 ms ± 9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Original method
25.3 s ± 497 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```